# time bar issue react-native-video

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-native-video

I am using react-native-video and react-native-media-controls to make a video playing component.

I am able to run the video and everything is working fine. But I wanted a functionality which when clicked on fullscreen view, then same video has to run on a modal.

Video is even running on top of modal. The issue is when in both background and modal video are running then time bar of video is acting odd. Time bar oscillates between two different times.

I am not able to figure out what the issue is.

```
const ChatVideoPlayerComponent = () => {
  const videoPlayer = useRef<any>(null);
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
  const [isFullScreen, setIsFullScreen] = useState(false);
  const [isPlayerLoading, setIsPlayerLoading] = useState(true);
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);
  const [playerState, setPlayerState] = useState(PLAYER_STATES.PLAYING);
  const [screenType, setScreenType] = useState('content');
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const onSeek = (seek: any) => {
    videoPlayer.current.seek(seek);
    console.log('seek');
  };

  const onPaused = (playerState: any) => {
    setPaused(!paused);
    setPlayerState(playerState);
  };

  const onReplay = () => {
    setPlayerState(PLAYER_STATES.PLAYING);
    videoPlayer.current.seek(0);
  };

  const onProgress = (data: any) => {
    if (!isPlayerLoading && playerState !== PLAYER_STATES.ENDED) {
      setCurrentTime(data.currentTime);
    }
  };

  const onLoad = (data: any) => {
    setDuration(data.duration);
    setIsPlayerLoading(false);
  };

  const onLoadStart = (data: any) => setIsPlayerLoading(true);

  const onEnd = () => setPlayerState(PLAYER_STATES.ENDED);

  const onError = () => {
    console.log('error');
  };

  const onFullScreen = () => {
    setIsFullScreen(isFullScreen);
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
    if (screenType == 'content') setScreenType('cover');
    else setScreenType('content');
  };

  const renderToolbar = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.toolbar}> toolbar </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const onSeeking = (currentTime: any) => {
    setCurrentTime(currentTime);
    console.log('seeking');
  };

  const fullScreenModal = () => {
    return (
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}>
        <View style={styles.modalContainer2}>
          <View style={styles.modalView2}>
            <View style={styles.modalCloseContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                }}>
                <ImageConfig.CloseCircle height={'25'} width={'25'} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                alignItems: 'center',
                marginVertical: 25,
              }}>
              <Video
                onEnd={onEnd}
                onLoad={onLoad}
                onLoadStart={onLoadStart}
                onProgress={onProgress}
                paused={paused}
                ref={videoPlayer}
                resizeMode={'cover'}
                onFullScreen={isFullScreen}
                source={{uri: 'https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/download/mixkit-countryside-meadow-4075.mp4'}}
                style={{height: 200, width: '100%'}}
                volume={10}
                onError={onError}
                repeat={true}
              />
              <View
                style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  top: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  height: 200,
                  width: '100%',
                }}>
                <MediaControls
                  duration={duration}
                  isLoading={isPlayerLoading}
                  mainColor="#333"
                  onFullScreen={onFullScreen}
                  onPaused={onPaused}
                  onReplay={onReplay}
                  onSeek={onSeek}
                  onSeeking={onSeeking}
                  playerState={playerState}
                  progress={currentTime}
                  toolbar={renderToolbar()}></MediaControls>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
      <Video
        onEnd={onEnd}
        onLoad={onLoad}
        onLoadStart={onLoadStart}
        onProgress={onProgress}
        paused={paused}
        ref={videoPlayer}
        resizeMode={'cover'}
        onFullScreen={isFullScreen}
        source={{uri: 'https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/download/mixkit-countryside-meadow-4075.mp4'}}
        style={{height: 200, width: 200}}
        volume={10}
        onError={onError}
        repeat={true}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,
          height: 200,
          width: '100%',
        }}>
        <MediaControls
          duration={duration}
          isLoading={isPlayerLoading}
          mainColor="#333"
          onFullScreen={onFullScreen}
          onPaused={onPaused}
          onReplay={onReplay}
          onSeek={onSeek}
          onSeeking={onSeeking}
          playerState={playerState}
          progress={currentTime}
          toolbar={renderToolbar()}></MediaControls>
        {fullScreenModal()}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  toolbar: {
    marginTop: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  modalContainer2: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#000000A0',
  },
  modalView2: {
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 20,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  modalCloseContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingTop: 10,
  },
});

export default ChatVideoPlayerComponent;
```